# Call perform_search in OrderWidget in method click_line Odoo POS

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

Im customizing the Odoo POS

screens.js:

```
ProductCategoriesWidget.include({   
template: 'ProductCategoriesWidget',        
    perform_search: function(category, query, buy_result){
        var products;          
    },    
});
```

Extending the Order Widget

```
OrderWidget.include({
template:'OrderWidget',
click_line: function(orderline, event)
{
var select_product = orderline.get_product();
var category = {"id":0,"name":"Root"};
select_product.perform_search(category, "i-pad" ,true);
},  });
```

"perform_search" method is in **ProductCategoriesWidget** template ...

My query is  how to call this method in Order Widget ?